# How redirect while waiting for a response using react-router

Tags: reactjs, openid

I'm trying to redirect from Login Component to DashBoard Component.

In this case my Login Component is called CodeClient and DashBoard Component is called IndexComponent.

My problem is that CodeClient Component makes request to authenticate with openid and when it makes the callback it doesn't enter `sendToken(code, status)` because it doesn't get info.I would like to redirect before to get the code and make the request.

If the render only contains:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <CodeClient />
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Enter on `sendToken(code, status)` and create the cookie and url shows next: `http://localhost:3000/loginCallback?code=ab4d60814c50fe66de0bd9z4a3318f12&session_state=mVnqjmlT4gyTslk0cwbYeSOvxIKHqIl85pPX6Gh7f1c.63dfcdf9691b3ebcdd0cb28dcac27e94`

But when I'm trying to make as I showed in one second show previous url and change for this: `http://localhost:3000/login`

My idea, is that user should not have access to any route without permissions and when user will be authenticated and refresh navigator continue on index page.

I'm not sure if I'm doing well and I'm going crazy to solve the problem the enter on `getToken` make the request, wait, create cookie and redirect to index.

Thanks and sorry for my English

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';
import CodeClient from './components/Login/CodeClient';
import IndexComponent from './components/Index/IndexComponent';

const checkAuth = () => {
    const cookie = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookie'));
    if (!cookie) return false;
    try {
        const exp = cookie.exp;
        const current = new Date().getTime();
        if (exp < current) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

const Home = (props) => {
    if (checkAuth() === true) {
        return <IndexComponent {...props} />
    }
    return <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
    }} />
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
        checkAuth() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
        <Redirect
            to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
            }}
        />
        )
    }
    />
);

class App extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" component={CodeClient} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

CodeClient.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './CodeClient.css';
import request from 'request';

class CodeClient extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { messageError: '', ok: false };

        this.url = 'https://url_example/connect/authorize?scope=openid&response_type=code&client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/loginCallback';
        this.url = encodeURI(this.url);
    }

    handleLogin = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = this.url;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var url_string = window.location.href;
        var url = new URL(url_string);
        var code = url.searchParams.get("code");
        var session_state = url.searchParams.get("session_state");

        if (code) {
            this.sendToken(code, session_state);
        }
    }

    sendToken = (code, state) => {
        var options = { 
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            body: { 
                code: code,
                state: state
            },
            json: true 
        };

        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                this.setState({ messageError: 'Error al autenticarse: ', error, ok: false });
                // throw new Error(error);
            }

            if (body.ok === true) {
                this.createCookie(body);
                this.props.history.push('/');
            } else {
                this.setState({ messageError: 'El código ya no sirve', ok: false });
            }
        });
    }

    createCookie = (data) => {
        var info = {
            id: data.id,
            name: data.name,
            exp: new Date().getTime() + data.expires_in,
        };
        console.log(info)
        localStorage.setItem('cookie', JSON.stringify(info));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Menu">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="card card-container">
                        <img id="profile-img" className="profile-img-card" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" alt="logo" />
                        <p id="profile-name" className="profile-name-card"></p>

                        <form className="form-signin">
                            {
                                (this.state.ok === false) ? <span id="reauth-email" className="reauth-email error">{this.state.messageError}</span> : 
                                    <span id="reauth-email" className="reauth-email success">{this.state.messageError}</span>
                            }

                            <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" onClick={this.handleLogin} >Conectar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CodeClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution, but it is a bad solution or bad implemented.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import request from 'request';
import IndexComponent from './components/Index/IndexComponent';

const checkAuth = () => {
    const cookie = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookie'));
    if (!cookie) return false;
    try {
        const exp = cookie.exp;
        const current = new Date().getTime();
        if (exp < current) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // window.history.pushState("", "", '/');
        this.state = { logged: false, messageError: '', ok: false };

        this.url = 'https://url_example/connect/authorize?scope=openid&response_type=code&client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/loginCallback';
        this.url = encodeURI(this.url);
    }

    handleLogin = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = this.url;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var url_string = window.location.href;
        var url = new URL(url_string);
        var code = url.searchParams.get("code");
        var session_state = url.searchParams.get("session_state");

        if (code) {
            this.sendToken(code, session_state);
        }
    }

    sendToken = (code, state) => {
        var options = { 
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            body: { 
                code: code,
                state: state
            },
            json: true 
        };

        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                this.setState({ messageError: 'Error al autenticarse: ', error, ok: false });
                // throw new Error(error);
            }

            if (body.ok === true) {
                this.createCookie(body);
            } else {
                this.setState({ messageError: 'El código ya no sirve', ok: false });
            }
        });
    }

    createCookie = (data) => {
        var info = {
            id: data.id,
            name: data.name,
            exp: new Date().getTime() + data.expires_in,
        };
        localStorage.setItem('cookie', JSON.stringify(info));
        this.setState({ logged: true });
    }

    render() {
        if (checkAuth()) return <IndexComponent />;
        else {
            return (
                <div className="Menu">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="card card-container">
                            <img id="profile-img" className="profile-img-card" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" alt="logo" />
                            <p id="profile-name" className="profile-name-card"></p>

                            <form className="form-signin">
                                {
                                    (this.state.ok === false) ? <span id="reauth-email" className="reauth-email error">{this.state.messageError}</span> : 
                                        <span id="reauth-email" className="reauth-email success">{this.state.messageError}</span>
                                }

                                <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" onClick={this.handleLogin} >Conectar</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default App;
```

IndexComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './IndexComponent.css'

const checkAuth = () => {
    const cookie = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookie'));
    if (!cookie) return false;
    try {
        const exp = cookie.exp;
        const current = new Date().getTime();
        if (exp < current) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

class IndexComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        window.history.pushState("", "", '/menu');
        this.checkCookie();
    }

    checkCookie = () => {
        if (!checkAuth()) {
            this.logout();
        }
    }

    logout = () => {
        localStorage.setItem('cookie', null);
        window.location.href = '/';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Home!</h1>
                <p>Estas logueado! Muy bien!</p>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    this.logout()
                }}>Cerrar sesión</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default IndexComponent;
```